# Syncing Desktop iTunes Library to Laptop

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization

I have a Hackintosh dual booting Windows 8.1 and Yosemite. The two OS's share the same iTunes Library. Every time something new is added in either OS, I would like to be synced to my laptop's iTunes Library, and whenever I add something in my laptop's Library I want it to sync to the desktop, no matter what OS it's currently in.

Comment: Can't be done. Libraries have absolute paths. Adding one line to another library means you need to do an import...

Comment: What do you mean "@grgarside Fair point, objection withdrawn". I'm guessing I need to like go to that user or something? If so where?

Comment: Is there any solution that's semi close to what I'm looking for even if I have to manually do some things?